# ios NSDateFormatter date from string using literal date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create a date out of my date string that goes:

`Tue, 29 Jul 2014 17:22:30 +0200`

I am using this code but it still gives me null as I try to `dateFromString`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd LLL YYYY hh:mm:ss +0200"];
NSLog(@"The date: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:bazosItem.itemDate]);
```

so the output is:

```
The date: (null)
```

I have been searching for the right dateFormat in the internet and have rechecked it multiple times and I have no idea what is going wrong with the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your format, first the `YYYY` should be `yyyy` second the `hh` is for AM/PM hour not 24 hours for this you should use `HH`.

Third and most important you should the the date format in which language the date is by adding a locale:

```
NSString *temp = @"Tue, 29 Jul 2014 17:22:30 +0200";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss +0200"];
NSLog(@"The date: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:temp]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that I had forgotten to trim the date string before applying the dateFromString method.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format seems to be incorrect. Try the following

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0200"];
```

Comment: Nope, still (null), I have tried it with HH but not with MMM.

Comment: Try the exact one. Ia'm getting properly. And you should use small "yyyy" I made correction